# make registration in parts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration

I want to build a script a register form and then divide in to parts, let me demonstrate

1. Accept rules (then press Continue)
2. Type username, password (then press Continue)
3. E-mail (and so on) and then Continue
4. To finally put all data and submit in to a database

But I'm not really sure how to do it, should I use sessions?

Give me some ideas of how you would have done it.

Comment: Why so complicated? Just put everything on the same page.

Comment: There is a lot of images, text (role play) in term here, and I think it would be wise to split it up to not confuse the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do it in PHP, your best bet would be using PHP's [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Take input from the forms on each page and store it in a session.

Comment: I'm not pleased with the answers, I've gotten. Though I solved this problem myself after a lot of searching, and Session was my way to go. So I'll put this to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Insert all of the users information into a database in pieces with a timestamp, and if the user clicks cancel or doesn't come back to filling in their user info the database their information will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery SmartWizard](http://www.techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartWizard2/smartwizard2-validation.php) or something like that.